# PostgreSQL Database structure/ schema for anonymous data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, create-table

I was hoping to get some advice on how to approach an issue I am having to building a database for a reviewing website built with node js and SQL backend. For this website we want to take a review out of 10 for different users for some posts and get an average for each post. The only issue is we want it to remain anonymous, so nobody can go into the tables and edit or view the results. The current schema for the database is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email TEXT UNIQUE,
    password TEXT NOT NULL
    admin BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    avg_review INTEGER
)
```

So from a submit form on the website I want to add data to a table to collect review data so that can be fed in the posts table above to get the avg_review , so the average review data for a particular post. My trouble is making this anonymous and also making the vote per user unique.
**UPDATE:**
My initial thinking was to use the following :

```
  CREATE TABLE review (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id),
  review_value INTEGER
);
```

This would then populate the average review data in the posts table. However I am not sure how to keep this anonymous.

I considered splitting into two tables

```
  CREATE TABLE review (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id),
);

CREATE TABLE votecheck (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id),
);
```

This would then record the votes without seeing who done it, and also register whether a user had already voted for a post to later check for uniqueness.

I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this as I feel doing it the way last posted, it would not allow editing of values and future proofing it in the long run. Apologies in advance as I am a beginner with SQL databases. Any advice on how to better handle this is appreciated. Would access levels work better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it would not allow "editing of values and future proofing it in the long run". If you want to hide who voted for what and yet be able to check if vote had place, you can use some hashing. Eg, lets assume user 1 voted on post 1 and 2, then you can have a table:

```
create table vote_placed(c uuid pk);
```

so when you vote, you do

```
insert into vote_placed select md5('1,1')::uuid;
insert into vote_placed select md5('1,2')::uuid;
```

so if you try to vote again you get an exception because of duplicate PK.

to check if the user voted, you can

```
select true from vote_placed where c = md5('1,1')::uuid
```

and yet just selecting the table wont give you obvious info on who voted on what... so you avoid the case when for one post only one person voted and knowing that you know who gave the exact vote - of course you can check if somebody voted, but you cant be sure there was only one person. also to mask first voter you can prefill the vote_placed table with random white noise, like `md5('manah, manah')::uuid`

Comment: So would this be the case of having two tables rather than the one that I have shown? Would this allow one to get the average though?

Comment: this one would replace votecheck and make it less obvious to read

Comment: If it is hashed is there a way to get out the vote to add to the posts table as an average? Also by editting of values I meant more, if a user made a mistake and wants to change their review, is this possible?

Comment: So is there a way to do a table like, but have it so the review value can be hashed out but still can make be used to calculate averages:
 CREATE TABLE review (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  post_id INTEGER REFERENCES posts(id),
  revew_value Integer
);